# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toObjects' of undefined in Meteor

Tags: meteor

Im Getting this error when running my project, any ideas?

The error is : **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toObjects' of undefined.**

Please see the below code once :

```
Members = new Meteor.Collection("members");

if (Meteor.isClient) {


    var fileName = '';
    Template.hello.events({
        'change input': function(ev) {

            fileName = ev.currentTarget.files;

            console.log("fileName : "+ fileName);

        _.each(ev.currentTarget.files, function(file) {
                Meteor.saveFile(file, file.name ,file.type);
            });
        }
    });

    Template.hello.events({
        'click #uploadTestFile':function(e){

            console.log("Btn Clicked......."+fileName);


            var files = fileName;

            for (var i = 0, file; file = files[i]; i++)
            {
                if (file.type.indexOf("text") == 0)
                {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onloadend = function (e)
                    {
                        var text = e.target.result;
                        console.log(text)
                        var all = $.csv.toObjects(text);
                        console.log(all)
                        _.each(all, function (entry)
                        {
                            Members.insert(entry);
                        });
                    }
                    reader.readAsText(file);
                }
            }
        }

    });
Meteor.saveFile = function(blob, name, type, path, callback) {

//Here some code

  }
}
```

I am not getting any idea.So please suggest me what to do for this ?

Comment: What is you console output from ```console.log(all)```?

Comment: this means that your JQuery variable $.csv is undefined. You will need to install the JQuery plugin i guess.